# iOS how to go from xib file to a view controller in tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xib

i have a tab bar application 
i am using storyboards and also navigation bar in my app

in my app

FirstViewController (in tab bar) with a button go to the SingleViewController (xib file and not on tab bar)

in SingleViewController there is a button too. and i want to go to one of the controllers which is on tab bar

in singleviewController's button method i have this code:

```
AylikGirisViewController *controller = [[AylikGirisViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

it goes to the controller but i see a black screen and empty screen also moving to the AylikGirisViewController gets hard (i mean very slowly)

so i think my way is wrong

any ideas for the right way?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboard, you can simply drag another view controller onto the storyboard and give name as `SingleViewController`, you can easily push the `SingleViewController` onto the `FirstViewController` if you embed the FirstViewController in `UINavigationController`. Use storyboard segue to push the controller. Then you can call UITabBarController Delegate method to show the different viewController.